# Angular 2 'Refused to execute from ..' JSONP issue.

Tags: json, angular, jsonp

I wiped my HD clean yesterday and installed Windows 10 pro.

I installed node/npm, git, etc.. and ran "npm install" on a project I was working on under Windows 8.1 (which worked).

The project relies on a service that connects to the Behance.net API.

When I type "ng serve", I get an error in the console.

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/dennisschafer/projects?api_key=myapikey&callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: null
```

Mind you, this project worked yesterday under my other environment, and I haven't touched any of the code since.

Here's what the service file looks like:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class BehanceService{
    private username:string = 'dennisschafer'; // dennisschafer
    private api_key = 'myapikey';

    constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) {

    }

    getProjects() {
        return this._jsonp.get('http://www.behance.net/v2/users/'+this.username+'/projects?api_key='+this.api_key+'&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK')
        .map(res => res.json());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue earlier today in my AngularJS 1.x app. My understanding of the problem is that the Behance Api is not returning the correct MIME type in the Content-Type header for JSONP requests. It is currently coming back as `application/json` when it should be [`application/javascript` or `text/javascript`](https://blog.tompawlak.org/json-jsonp-correct-mime-type). The error is coming from Chrome as it's a security restriction and refuses to the let the code run with the wrong MIME type. I checked some other browsers and firefox seems to be ok with it. So I don't think there's anything to do on your end. You can submit a request [here](https://help.behance.net/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=4164) like I did and hope they fix it soon. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, that's crazy if they changed something literally within the 20 hours that I was down, doing an upgrade from a different OS.

Comment: Yep, last night it started working all the sudden and it's returning application/javascript.  Thanks.